# filter observations within date interval or NA

Tags: r, date, dplyr, tidyr, na

I want to check observations for a certain date interval or NA and then create new variable. See example:

```
d <- wrapr::build_frame( "ID", "DATE1", "DATE2" | 1 , "2001-03-05" , "2001-01-05" | 2 , "2001-01-02" , "NA" | 3 , "2001-01-02" , "2004-04-01" | 4 , "2012-01-02" , "2012-01-02" )
```

Generates this:

```
  ID      DATE1   DATE2     
1  1 2001-03-05 2001-01-05  
2  2 2001-01-02 NA      
3  3 2001-01-02 2004-04-01  
4  4 2012-01-02 2012-01-02
```

And I want the result to be like this:

```
  ID      DATE1   DATE2     VAR
1  1 2001-03-05 2001-01-05  2001-01-05
2  2 2001-01-02 NA          0
3  3 2001-01-02 2004-04-01  0
4  4 2012-01-02 2012-01-02  2012-01-02
```

That is, `DATE1` should be greater or equal than `DATE2`, but not more than 90 days.

If this is true `DATE2` should be written in new column `VAR`.

If this isn´t true or `DATE2` is NA, `VAR` should be 0.

I´ve been trying to use `dplyr`, but can´t really figure out how to solve it.

```
d<-d%>%group_by(ID)%>%filter(is.na(DATE2)|((DATE1-DATE2)>0)
d<-d%>%group_by(ID)%>%filter(is.na(DATE2)|((DATE1-DATE2)<90)
```

Best,
H

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible solution using `dplyr` would be

```
library(dplyr)

d %>% 
  mutate(
    DATE1 = as.Date(DATE1),
    DATE2 = as.Date(DATE2),
    VAR = ifelse(DATE1 >= DATE2 & as.numeric(difftime(DATE1, DATE2, units = "days")) < 90 & !is.na(DATE2), as.character(DATE2), 0)
  )
```

Output

```
#   ID      DATE1      DATE2        VAR
# 1  1 2001-03-05 2001-01-05 2001-01-05
# 2  2 2001-01-02       <NA>          0
# 3  3 2001-01-02 2004-04-01          0
# 4  4 2012-01-02 2012-01-02 2012-01-02
```

Comment: Thanks. Worked fine. If I then want to just keep the highest DATE2 per ID (not applicable on this test df). How do I do it?

Comment: You can add `!is.na(DATE2)` condition inside `ifelse()` and then omit the `replace_na()` function at the end.

Comment: @PetrKajzar I've tried that, but in that case the second value for `VAR` remains `NA` instead of turning into zero

Comment: @hkolvs Glad I could help, please consider upvoting the answer if you found it useful. For your other question, I think that it could be another question to ask as it is quite different, but I assume you have to group by `ID` and then filter only the row (per group) with the max `DATE2`

Comment: @RicS Ah, for me it works properly: `d %>% mutate(DATE1 = as.Date(DATE1), DATE2 = as.Date(DATE2), VAR = ifelse(!is.na(DATE2) & DATE1 >= DATE2 & as.numeric(difftime(DATE1, DATE2, units = "days")) < 90, as.character(DATE2), 0))`

Comment: @PetrKajzar now it works for me too.. Maybe I messed up something with the `&` operator.. I will edit my answer with your suggestion, thank you!